# How to control the app version on Google Play Console?

Tags: testing, google-play-console

we've got an app that's not on the market yet and we are struggling with the testing version that testers download. We're trying to set the v1.0.1 but Google Play redirects them to v1.0.0 which is not up to date. We even tried to deactivate that branch but the issue still insists.

Answer (score 0):

I do a lot of test deployments for multiple test groups.

Google supports 3 separate types of test groups: **Open**, **Closed**, **Internal**.

**Open Testing** is literally open to anyone who wants to opt in and they can join via a link you can copy from the developer console. Open testing requires the app go thru review before being rolled out.

**Closed Testing** is similar to Open but you explicitly define who has access with a list of email addresses. Closed testing must also pass through a basic Google review before being rolled out.

**Internal Testing** is similar to Closed testing but it never goes through a review process. Again, this is controlled via a list of email addresses.

I routinely publish different versions where Internal has the latest bleeding edge.

[image: Publishing Overview]

You don't state which channel you are using (Open, Closed, Internal), but I would carefully review each channel and the email addresses associated. Then I would click on the **Publishing Overview** button on the console to see if there's something you haven't finished.